# Copy data from one workbook to another when the file name is never the same

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a macro so i can open two identical workbooks but both will have constantly changing different file names and then copy a few data ranges from source to target. 
I have tried to put together something from a few different places but am getting lost with it so i was hoping someone could shed some new light for me.

VBA for Excel 2016

```
Sub Button33_Click()


Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim targetBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

' Must have exactly 2 workbooks open
If Workbooks.Count <> 2 Then 'if it is equal to 2 it will not work
    MsgBox "Open the calculation form that you want to copy from", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Copy Data From Old to New Sheets"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Set the source and target workbooks
Set targetBook = ActiveWorkbook

Set sourceBook = Workbooks(1)


' Setting up the sheets
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.ActiveSheet
Set targetSheet = targetBook.ActiveSheet

' Copy the data from the cells

sourceSheet.Range("D14:D18").Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("D14:D18")
sourceSheet.Range("A2").Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A2")
sourceSheet.Range("B5").Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B5")
sourceSheet.Range("E26").Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E26")
sourceSheet.Range("G14").Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Range("G14")


End Sub
```

The wrong data is being copied and i cant figure out where it is coming from.

Comment: Try using `Set sourceBook = ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks, the workbook where the macro is located is the target, the problem seems to be that it is not using the correct reference for the source

Comment: Also according to Tom's comment, change every 'ActiveSheet' to specified sheet for example sheets("NameOfSheet")

Comment: Yes i tried that previously but seem to get a "Script out of range" error on the line

Comment: Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Fixed Costs Calc")

Comment: Changing the Workbook.Count as above to <>2 makes the error window always flag, even if two workbooks are open?